# Pygame Tetris Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tetris

I've been writing a very rudimentary version of Tetris for Pygame in python 3.6. The only features so far are the blocks falling, making them fall faster, moving left and right, and when a block hits the ground, a new one spawns.

However, there is the issue. When the first block hits the ground, blocks spawn indefinitely at the top of the screen. I scoured the code and also showed it to my friend, and we couldn't find the issue. I scrapped the code and rewrote it, and the problem persisted. Does anyone here see it?

Thanks

P.S.
I'm pretty sure that the top 2/3 of the code is not the issue.

```
import pygame, random

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tetris")
done = False
fast = False
locked = False
fallingblocks = []
setblocks = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fallcooldown = 0

class Block:

  def __init__(self, x, y, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.color = color
    fallingblocks.append(self)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x + 1, self.y, 23, 25) #game only cares if falling block collides on the top or bottom, not side

  def fall(self):
    self.y += 25

  def move(self):
    if pressed[pygame.K_a] or pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.x -= 25
    if pressed[pygame.K_d] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.x += 25

  def drawblock(self): #just to make it look nice
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color[0], pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,25,25))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.color[1], ((self.x,self.y),(self.x+3,self.y+3),(self.x+21,self.y+3),(self.x+24,self.y)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.color[2], ((self.x,self.y),(self.x+3,self.y+3),(self.x+3,self.y+21),(self.x,self.y+24)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.color[3], ((self.x,self.y+24),(self.x+3,self.y+21),(self.x+21,self.y+21),(self.x+24,self.y+24)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.color[4], ((self.x+24,self.y+24),(self.x+21,self.y+21),(self.x+21,self.y+3),(self.x+24,self.y)))

def spawn():
  blocknum = random.randint(0,6)

  if blocknum == 0:
    #I block
    colors = [(129,184,231),
    (179,223,250),
    (146,202,238),
    (76,126,189),
    (96,157,213)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(175,25,colors)
    Block(175,50,colors)
    Block(175,75,colors)
  elif blocknum == 1:
    #J block
    colors = [(77,110,177),
    (149,178,229),
    (104,145,203),
    (49,63,136),
    (63,85,158)]

    Block(200,0,colors)
    Block(200,25,colors)
    Block(200,50,colors)
    Block(175,50,colors)
  elif blocknum == 2:
    #L block
    colors = [(219,127,44),
    (243,191,122),
    (229,158,69),
    (166,71,43),
    (193,98,44)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(175,25,colors)
    Block(175,50,colors)
    Block(200,50,colors)  
  elif blocknum == 3:
    #O block
    colors = [(248,222,49),
    (246,243,139),
    (245,235,86),
    (183,160,54),
    (213,190,55)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(175,25,colors)
    Block(200,0,colors)
    Block(200,25,colors)
  elif blocknum == 4:
    #S block
    colors = [(156,195,76),
    (204,218,127),
    (174,208,79),
    (109,157,75),
    (140,183,93)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(175,25,colors)
    Block(200,0,colors)
    Block(150,25,colors)   
  elif blocknum == 5:
    #Z block
    colors = [(204,42,40),
    (226,138,132),
    (213,90,69),
    (151,34,42),
    (181,37,43)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(225,25,colors)
    Block(200,0,colors)
    Block(200,25,colors)
  else:
    #T block
    colors = [(147,68,149),
    (187,145,194),
    (156,101,167),
    (108,45,123),
    (128,47,135)]

    Block(175,0,colors)
    Block(175,25,colors)
    Block(200,0,colors)
    Block(150,0,colors)

spawn()

#Pretty sure that everything above here is not the issue

while not done: #main loop

  screen.fill((0,0,32))
  pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

  for fallingblock in fallingblocks:
    fallingblock.drawblock()
    fallingblock.move()

  for setblock in setblocks:
    setblock.drawblock()

  if fallcooldown >= 50: #makes all pieces fall at once
    for fallingblock in fallingblocks:
      fallingblock.fall()
    fallcooldown = 0
  pygame.display.flip()

  if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]: #if you want the piece to go the ground instantly
    fast = True

  if fast: fallcooldown = 50 #falling movements
  elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: fallcooldown += 8 #goes faster
  else: fallcooldown += 1 #default speed

  for fallingblock in fallingblocks:
    for setblock in setblocks:
      if fallingblock.rect.colliderect(setblock.rect): #if fallingblock collides with setblock
        locked = True
    if fallingblock.y >= 575 and not locked: #if block hits the bottom
      locked = True

  if locked: #if block is in final state
    setblocks += fallingblocks 
    fallingblocks = []
    spawn()
    locked = False

  clock.tick(50)
  pygame.display.flip()

  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          done = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused in the `fall` method of the `Block`. You only change the `y` attribute but never move the `rect` of the block, so it actually stays at the top of the screen the whole time. So remove the `x, y` attributes and just use `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`, or alternatively set `self.rect.y = self.y`.

To debug the code I first printed `print(locked, len(fallingblocks), len(setblocks))` above the `if locked:` line to confirm that `locked` was always `True` after the first block touched the ground. Then I tried to comment out the collision detection with the `setblocks` and the continuous spawning stopped. The next step was to print the rects of the setblocks and fallingblocks and it revealed that the y-pos of the rects was always 0 or 25 and never changed. I looked at the movement code in the `fall` method and noticed that the rect doesn't get moved.

There are more issues, but I think you should try to continue with the debugging first and ask new questions if you still have trouble.